# How to structure views for database pulling and manipulation

Tags: django, django-views, django-database

I am having difficulties understanding how best to structure my views.
I am pulling data on various users and creating variables that summarise some of these variables (such as occurrences per week etc). This is so I can graph these summary variables in my templates. I am doing quite a lot of different manipulations which is getting quite messy , and i shall need these manipulations for other templates. Can somebody recommend how best to structure views in this case. I think using classes is the solution to use the same functions for other templates but I cannot quite understand how. I also feel there must be a better way to structure each manipulation of database data.

```
def dashboard(request):

    posts= Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    posts_count = posts.count()
    post_early = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user).earliest('date')   #need to extract the date value from this so I can take the difference

    total_days = (datetime.datetime.now().date()- post_early.date).days

    average_30days= round((posts_count/total_days)*30,2)

    list4=[]
    list5=[]
    i=1
    time3=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(-30)

    while i<32:

        list4.append(days2(time3,request,Post))
        list5.append(time3.strftime('%b %d, %Y'))
        i+=1
        time3=time3 + datetime.timedelta(+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dashboardView(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    posts_count = posts.count()
    #need to extract the date value from post_early so I can take the difference
    post_early = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user).earliest('date')   
    total_days = (datetime.datetime.now().date() - post_early.date).days
    average_30days = round((posts_count/total_days)*30,2)
    list_4 = []
    list_5 = []
    i = 1
    time_3=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(-30)

    while i<32:
        list_4.append(days2(time_3, request, Post))
        list_5.append(time_3.strftime('%b %d, %Y'))
        i += 1
        time_3 = time_3 + datetime.timedelta(1)
```

I'd do something like this. There were a few inconsistency:

-keep a space before and a space after operators (=, *, -, +, ...).

-I'd consider a good practice to always suffix -View to your views, but it's just personal preference

-Use empty lines to separate blocks of code, not groups of variables. If you have a long list of variables declarations (not this case) you can use comments to separate and categorize them.

-Use list_3 instead of list3 (and similar cases), it's more readable.

For more you can always check the official python style guide: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Anyway, if you're consistent and attain to the coding style used in the Django documentation while learning, you'll be fine.

##### EDIT:

Note: my answer is based on the code you provided, which seems cut (no return statement?) and without the other modules.

You're using a function based view which is not wrong nor correct, just one of the possible choices. If you don't like it, or want to try something else, a ListView may work for you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/

Example:

```
from django.views import ListView

class DashboardView(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        # add all the data you need to the context dictionary
    return context
```

Comment: this doesn't answer my question at all. I am asking about structure using classes other any other options not line spacing and naming conventions.

Comment: Sorry then, I thought you were asking how to organize your code (which definitely wouldn't hurt in this case, and would help preventing from getting messy. I'll try to answer your question with an edit to my previous answer.